# Add custom fields to an existing entity

Tags: 8, entities, webforms

I would like to add extra fields to an existing entity WebformSubmission :

- Assigned to (entity reference to a user)
- Status ( taxonomy term reference)

for these two fields I will need it to be available in Views.

what is the right method ?